# How many subgroups of order 3 can G have. $|G| = 231$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would I find the maximum amount of subgroups of order $3$ that $G$ can have if $|G| = 231$?

I know by Sylow's first theorem that $G$ must have at least 1 subgroup of order $3$ since $3$ divides the order of $G$.  However, I do not know how to determine how many possible subgroups $G$ can have over order $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $231=3\cdot 7\cdot 11$. By Sylow I and III we have that $n_3\mid 77$ and $n_3\equiv 1\bmod 3$. So $n_3=1$, or $n_3=7$. For the Sylow-$7$-subgroups and Sylow-$11$-subgroups we obtain $n_7=n_{11}=1$.

So any group of order $231$ contains a unique (normal) Sylow
$7$-subgroup and a central Sylow $11$-subgroup (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296337/subgroup-of-order-11-lies-inside-zg)); it contains either one or seven Sylow $3$-subgroups. If it contains only one, then $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: To see that $n_3=7$ actually occurs, consider $(Z_7\rtimes Z_3)\times Z_{11}$

Comment: Why must $n_3$ divide $77$?

Comment: Dear MomoTheSir; the Sylow theorem says: "$n_p$ divides $m$, which is the index of the Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G$." The index is $231/3=77$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

Comment: I understand your argument that there can be a maximum of 7 Sylow 3-subgroups, but does this also mean that there can be a maximum of 7 subgroups of order 3 as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that every subgroup of G of order 3 must live inside a Sylow 3-subgroup.